# Jquery UI dialog doesn't open multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i'm trying to load a page into a dialog box with jquery-ui, but the dialog opens just one time.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#clickToOpen").click( function() {

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal:true,
                draggable:false,
                resizable:false,
                minWidth: 900,
                maxWidth: 300,
                minHeight: 300,
                maxHeight: 800,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 400
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 400
                },
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                }
            });

            $("#dialog").load('login.htm');
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
   });
```

When i try to reopen the dialog i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have to know i've tryed to initializate the dialog outside the click event, but i still got the error.

Some Help?

EDIT: if i remove the .load function, i can open the dialog multiple times.. but i dont understand how to fix this.

Comment: Tough to tell without the rest of your code. Are you able to provide some of the HTML and in particular the dialog login HTML? Without more info I think you're best bet would be to make sure the dialog is getting closed correctly.

Comment: Try changing `$("#dialog").load('login.htm');` to `$("#dialog").load('login.htm *');`. It will prevent the <script>s in login.htm from running.